# Getting Unknown failure (-XX:mainThreadStackSize=N) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run app from Android Studio to my phone then I am always getting error in Android Studio as **Unknown failure (-XX:mainThreadStackSize=N)**

[image]

I tried below things and is no luck:

1. Connected phone via USB
2. Connected phone via Wifi and without USB
3. Restart the phone.

Note:
Above issue I am only facing on *Samsung Galaxy J3 SM-J320F*

Can anyone solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this also happen when you try to build (and not deploy) the app? `Build > Clean Project` then `Build > Rebuild Project`

Comment: @MichaelDodd Now I tried your suggestion too but still same issue

Comment: That's fine, was just trying to determine where then problem was happening. Could you please go to the Terminal and type `./gradlew clean build` (Mac/Linux) or `gradlew.bat clean build` (Windows) and post any messages around the error into your question?

Comment: after 'gradlew.bat clean build' i got error to resolve lint errors from project. and there are around 120 lint errors. What you suggest I have to solve all?

Comment: Add `lintOptions {  abortOnError false }` to your `build.gradle` inside the `android` section and rebuild. Out of interest, did @LearningAlways answer solve your issue?

Comment: @LearningAlways didn't solve my issue. I added lintOptions too but same issue.

Comment: Ok, can you copy and paste the errors from the gradle build into your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164610/discussion-between-nikhil-lotke-and-michael-dodd).

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Instant Run in Android Studio.
AS steps below:

Go To this:-
**--File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment.**

-- then Click on Instant Run and unckeck "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy".

-- Click on "Apply" and "OK".

-- clean build your project

Try to run again. It Should work.

Comment: I tried your solution and after that everytime I am getting message as 'Client not ready yet..'

Comment: after disable your instant run ,, did you try enable again and run?

Comment: yes i tried and getting same message  'Client not ready yet..'